# Show filename only in tabs (terminal vim)

Tags: vim

How can I show only the file name on vim tabs (e.g. "file.py" instead of "n/t/s/file.py") for terminal vim?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468939/how-to-let-tab-display-only-file-name-rather-than-the-full-path-in-vim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer by malexander only works with gvim. 
For terminal (console) vim I had to use:

```
set tabline=
```

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
:set guitablabel=%t
```

I found it here, may be more info of use:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/9f7BM8v3FhA

Comment: This is for Gvim only?